# What is an 'uDApp'?

Tags: contract-development, dapps, dapp-development, greeter

The [online solidity compiler](https://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/) offers an output of smart contracts labelled *uDApp*, for example the greeter uDApp looks like that:

```
[{"name":"greeter","interface":"[{\"constant\":false,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"kill\",\"outputs\":[],\"type\":\"function\"},{\"constant\":true,\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"greet\",\"outputs\":[{\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"name\":\"_greeting\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"type\":\"constructor\"}]\n","bytecode":"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"}]
```

What is an 'uDApp'? What can I do with this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A uDApp is short for [Universal DApp](https://github.com/d11e9/universal-dapp) and is described as "A Universal Interface for contracts on the Ethereum blockchain".

As the project hasn't been maintained for 5 months and the [demo](http://d11e9.github.io/universal-dapp) is currently broken (Reference and Type errors if you open Javascript console), it's hard to picture what it would have done.

My guess is it would have shown the different functions of the provided contracts, and input fields for interacting with the functions.  It may have already been fully integrated into the [Solidity Browser](http://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity), for example the red "Create" button and all the interactive elements once a contract has been created.